# select different value according to different condition

Tags: php, mysql

How to select and sum different values according to different condition in mysql and PHP in a single statement. Please look at the picture for understanding the concept clearly. Thanks

[image]

Comment: You won't get much help I'm afraid... as I read your question 3 times and don't understand a single thing.  Also, why would you use an example city that's not even on your image.

Comment: Please read the question again, hope this time you will understand. Please also check the image which will clear it for you

Comment: Do you really have two tables as I have edited in the question?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, SO is not a free coding service

Comment: Basically I have one order table. Which contains name, city, amount and date&time.
customers orders form many different cities in different time. City can be same. for example a customer

Comment: I have in my DATABASE
City Date&Time   Amount 
A 11/25/2015 10:55   552 
B 10/2/2015 10:55   26 
B 12/11/2015 10:55   366 
D 10/2/2015 10:55   11441 
A 11/29/2015 10:55   5555 
B 10/2/2015 10:55   225 
A 12/1/2015 10:55   5555 
C 12/30/2015 10:55   2541 
  
   
     
I want      
City Date&Time November December so on… 
A Nov sum(of Nov. Amount) sum(of Dec. Amount) sum(so on…) 
B Nov sum(of Nov. Amount) sum(of Dec. Amount) sum(so on…) 
C Nov sum(of Nov. Amount) sum(of Dec. Amount) sum(so on…) 
D Nov sum(of Nov. Amount) sum(of Dec. Amount) sum(so on…)

Comment: This question is getting worse and worse. Now it's just 2 lines of text without any images.

Comment: You'll never manage to query your months as columns. Grouping your results per month will show them as rows.  
On top of that your question is way too broad and you're expecting someone else to write your code, which is not what this site is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general strategy is like this:

```
SELECT City,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(DateColumn) = 1, AmountColumn, 0)) AS JanuaryTotal,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(DateColumn) = 2, AmountColumn, 0)) AS FebruaryTotal,
    . . .
    SUM(IF(MONTH(DateColumn) = 12, AmountColumn, 0)) AS DecemberTotal
FROM YourTable
WHERE YEAR(DateColumn) = 2015
GROUP BY City
```

Comment: Only when the OP doesn't have data across various years and wants those separated.

Comment: Same strategy, more complicated `IF` statements.  User must, however, know what years and months should be in the result set.

Comment: That's what I meant.. unless you want to write a 50000 character query covering all months from 1970 -> 2030.  Good luck with that one!

Comment: The OP's question does not cover multiple years, therefore the simple case discussed above should answer the question as asked.  However, when this kind of question rears its head in the real world its *almost* always limited to two years (showing monthly results year-over-year) or perhaps four quarters.  That's quite manageable with this type of query especially considering that the query itself can easily be built in code (with no worry about SQL injection since it doesn't involve any interpolation of strings from the user).

Comment: Lots of assumptions flying around here... but anyway... the OP turned out to be pretty bad at asking the question and now seems to be very absent... let's hope your answer made him at least a bit smarter ;)

Comment: Thank you all! I got my answer!